# knockoutjs submit binding not handling enter key properly

Tags: jquery-ui, submit, knockout.js

I have a jquery ui dialog with a knockoutjs submit binding on a form. The dialog can be closed either by pressing the cancel button, by pressing the close button on the dialog title bar, by hitting escape, or by pressing the save button. My intent is that the cancel, escape, and title bar close events should dismiss the dialog without applying any actions from it, whereas pressing enter or clicking 'save' should perform the dialog action. Everything works as intended, except the enter key, which results in a cancel event, rather than in a submit event.

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gene/HwbD2/) to illustrate this, and include code below for referernce.

My apologies for the verbose code...

Gene

```
<!-- ko with: dialog -->
<div id="taskdlg" class="resizeableDialog" 
    data-bind="dialog: {autoOpen: false, title: 'Edit task', height: 200, width: 500, modal: true, close: updateCloseState}, openWhen: open">
    <form data-bind="submit: update">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 100px;"><label for="tasktitle">Title</label></td>
                <td width="*">
                    <input id="tasktitle" type="text" placeholder="Task name" data-bind="value: titletext, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button style="float: left;" data-bind="click: cancel">Cancel</button></td>
                <td><button style="float: right;" type="submit">Save</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<button data-bind="click: editTask">Edit</button>
<span data-bind="text: task"></span>
```

The javascript is as follows:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dialog = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        setTimeout(function() { $(element).dialog(options || {}); }, 0);

        //handle disposal (not strictly necessary in this scenario)
         ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
             $(element).dialog("destroy");
         });   
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
         var shouldBeOpen = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(allBindingsAccessor().openWhen);
         $(element)
             .dialog(shouldBeOpen ? "open" : "close");
    }
};

function Task(name) {
    var self = this;
    this.title = ko.observable(name);

    this.toString = function() { return "Task: " + self.title(); };
}

function TaskDialog(viewModel) {
    var self = this;

    this.viewModel = viewModel;
    this.task = ko.observable();
    this.open = ko.observable(false);
    this.titletext = ko.observable();

    this.editTask = function(task) {
        self.task(task);
        self.titletext(task.title());
        self.open(true);
    }

    this.update = function() {
        var task = self.task();
        task.title(self.titletext());
        self.open(false);
    }

    this.updateCloseState = function() {
        if (self.open())
            self.open(false);
    }

    this.cancel = function() {
        self.open(false);
    }
}


function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.dialog = ko.observable(new TaskDialog(self));
    this.task = ko.observable(new Task('sample task'));

    this.editTask = function() {
        self.dialog().editTask(self.task());
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If a button does not have a type, then the browser makes an assumption that it can be considered a `submit` button.  So, when you hit `enter` the cancel button's method is being executed and preventing the default submit from actually happening.  So, if you were to move the Save button before the Cancel button it would work properly.

However, the real way to fix it is just to add `type="button"` to your Cancel:

```
<button type="button" style="float: left;" data-bind="click: cancel">Cancel</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/HwbD2/11/

Comment: Yes, I spent a long time looking at this one.  Just seemed like there was something small that we were missing and that it didn't require a whole bunch of code to capture keyCode 13, etc...